# Find global pattern matches

Tags: java, regex

I have a pattern like this:

```
String pattern = "(media:\\s\\d+)"
```

I want to match a substring variation of

```
"media:" + space/no space + X
```

...where **X** is a set of numbers. The pattern can appear anywhere in text and followed by anything.

Here's the example:

> "The Moment of Impact text: Camera captures the deadly explosions and
>   chaos near the marathon's finish line.**media: 18962980** Video shows
>   runner ... falling as a result of the blast **media: 18967421**A bystander
>   films the chaos of people positioned in between the two explosions."

For this my pattern returns only the first occurrence instead of all. 
Here is the code I'm using:

```
String pattern = "(media:\\s\\d+)"; 
Pattern media = Pattern.compile(pattern,Pattern.MULTILINE);
java.util.regex.Matcher m = media.matcher(text);        
if(m.find()) {
    logger.info("-- group:"+m.group());     
}
```

Comment: `String pattern = "(media:\\s?\\d+)"`?

Comment: Show the code please. Perhaps, just replace `if` with `while`? A capturing group around the whole pattern is redundant unless you split a string.

Answer (score 7):

This is a case of replacing the `if` with a `while`.  So long as the matcher isn't reset, [`Matcher#find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) will continue to match tokens until it exhausts the string.

You will also need to adjust the regex since you may or may not match spaces.  Use the expression `\\s?`, which either does or does not match a single space.

As a general tip, [`Pattern.MULTILINE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) only makes sense with anchors (`^` and `$`), and since you don't have any, you can safely remove it.  It's not doing any damage as is, but it will actively make your code less readable.

```
String pattern = "media:\\s?\\d+"; 
Pattern media = Pattern.compile(pattern);
java.util.regex.Matcher m = media.matcher(text);        
while(m.find()) {
    logger.info("-- group:"+m.group());     
}
```

Comment: Oh shoot! I see what you mean! Thank you!

Comment: Nice compilation of comments. :) Although I would use a different quantifier with `\s`.

Comment: You do not need the `Pattern.MULTILINE`, there is no `^`, nor `$` in the pattern.

Comment: @stribizhev:  I was more or less illustrating that, with only the modification to `while`, that their code would behave as they expect.  I'll go ahead and clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it didn't repeat or loop is because you didn't use a while statement. For it to work, change your if statement to while.

```
while(m.find()) {
    logger.info("-- group:"+m.group());     
}
```

Use this modification to your regex pattern:

```
String pattern = "(media:\\s?\\d+)"
```

The reason for the change ie `\\s?` is to enable you  match the pattern even if there is no space there. Hope this helps!

Comment: `[\\s+]?` may match a `+` symbol, too.

Comment: hmmmmmn. Never heard of that before.

Comment: Here, [look at this demo](https://regex101.com/r/mF4mW4/1) and study [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: thanks for the eye opening info. So can you provide a better way of making + not to be matched

Comment: Remove it from the character class.